# Npgsql >3.0 call function with null param without explicit cast

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

In npgsql 2 I could call function with null param and it actually worked.

```
select * from testfn(@test1);
AddWithValue("@test1", DBNull.Value)
```

Now in Npgsql 6 I got exception that there is no function with unknown parameter.

I don't want to rewrite all code to set type of params explicitly. Is there any workaround?

Comment: [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), you should specify parameter types and lengths exactly. So no, don't think there is a workaround

Comment: But sir, it worked in npgsql 2.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no workaround - null is not a valid way to specify database nulls in ADO.NET (that's what `DBNull.Value` is for). Npgsql 2 is an ancient version, and many behavioral things have been fixed since then, including some breaking changes.